# undefined local variable or method `user'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to do the following:

**index.html.erb**

```
<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

<script>
    $(function () {
        var chart;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart:{
                    renderTo:'container',
                    type:'column'
                },
                title:{
                    text:'<%= Date.today.strftime("%B")%> Overtime'
                },
                xAxis:{
                    categories:[

                        '<%= Date.today.strftime("%B")%>'

                    ]
                }, 
                yAxis:{
                    min:0,
                    title:{
                        text:'Hours'
                    }
                },
                legend:{
                    layout:'vertical',
                    backgroundColor:'#FFFFFF',
                    align:'left',
                    verticalAlign:'top',
                    x:100,
                    y:70,
                    floating:true,
                    shadow:true
                },
                tooltip:{
                    formatter:function () {
                        return '' +
                                'Hours' + ': ' + this.y;
                    },

                    credits:{
                        text:'migroup-.co.uk',
                        hreft:'http://wwww.migroup.co.uk'
                    }
                },
                plotOptions:{
                    column:{
                        pointPadding:0.4,
                        borderWidth:0
                    }
                },


                series:[
                    <% @user.hospital_bookings.each do |hospital_booking| %>

                    {
                        name:'<%= hospital_booking.try(:name)%>',
                        data:[<%= hospital_booking.sum(&:overtime)%>


                        ]
                        // color: '#8F8689',
                    },
                    <% end %>
                    {
                        name:'Total',
                        data: [<%= @hospital_bookings.to_a.sum(&:overtime)%>],
                        color:'#FE9D00'
                    }
                ]
            });
        });

    });


</script>
```

**controller.rb**

def index

```
@user = User.all
@hospital_bookings = HospitalBooking.scope
```

end
end

What I am trying to do is for each user, iterate over their bookings and sum their `overtime`.

Models

```
User.rb 
has_many :hospital_bookings 

Hospital_booking
belongs_to :user
```

What this will effectively do is get the user and sum their overtime hours. But for some reason this is not working. What I have at the moment is highcharts looking like the forward:

[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWTgu.png). Each bar represents a seperate hospital booking and their overtime. However I'd like to just total that Users overtime. So effectively it has one bar per user.

Comment: Judging from the error message in your question title, I would assume that whatever templating solution you are using needs to have the 'user' attribute bound before this text blob is templated.

Comment: Give us your `hospital_booking` model rb file.

Comment: @BenjaminM Added the models

Comment: you have removed `hospital_booking.user.try(:name)` ?! Has the error changed? Cause there's no more `user` inside your file ;)

Comment: @BenjaminM I get - `undefined method hospital_bookings for #<Array:0x59e7d00>`

Comment: If you get that error, it means that @user is not a User object, but an Array object, so at some point you are putting an Array within the atuser, can u update the question with the complete controller code for the action, and the complete view code, to see where the atuser is being updated? Otherwise if you use breakpoints you will be able to execute the app step by step and get the issue

Comment: @rorra I have updated to include my controller and view/index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the problem, you are doing:

```
@user = User.all
@user.hospital_bookings.each do |hospital_booking|
  ...
end
```

But the problem is that when you do User.all, you are getting an array of Users, not a single user, so if you do:

```
@users = User.all
@users.each do |user|
  user.hospital_bookings.each do |hospital_booking|
  end
end
```

that will work, however you may want to show the bookings of a single user, probably you need to do something like

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@user.hospital_bookings.each do |hospital_booking|
  ...
end
```

BTW, I'm on the health industry as well, feel free to ping me at anytime :)